# Scheduling time table with maximum jobs time.

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a problem where I have some time set (starting - ending )and I have to give the list so that maximum number of jobs get done.

1. I have solution where I use DP and solve it in On2

Can it be done in On ?

Comment: Do the jobs depend on each other?

Comment: No, they dont depend on each other All are independent

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but you can sort the list of jobs in O(nlogn) time, then start from the shortest and add the jobs until you've exceeded the set timeframe. What am I missing here?

Comment: @biziclop Lets consider 3 jobs: (1,10), (11.20) and (9,12). Your solution fails here.

Comment: @ElKamina Thanks, I know what I was missing. I thought the jobs can start at any time, only their lengths mattered. It all makes sense now.

Comment: @Arjit Can you describe your O(n^2) solution? I don't think one exists. If it does exist, I would use it rather than sub-optimal O(n) or O(nlogn) solutions (Eg. Greedy solution given below by yourself).

Comment: Yes O(n) solution is better to use. it can be a recursive solution where on each step you either choose or not to choose the other time slot. And memorize it. On each u can choose a time table in order N and all steps in Order N .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I got the solution it can be done by Greedy Algorithm 
For details : 
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2009/cmsc451/lectures/Lec04-interval.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let the jobs be j1(s1, e1), j2(s2, e2), ..., jn(sn, en)
where s1, s2, s3, ..., sn are the starting times of the jobs and
e1, e2, e3, ..., en are the ending times of the jobs.

Now sort the jobs according to their start times (si's)
(Use any of the algorithms (O(n lg n)).
Also note the job# (You can probably store the job# in another array.
As you do the sorting of the jobs' starting times, sort the corresponding job# array also).

Now take the last job from the list (which is now sorted), and put it into your final answer list.

Scan through the list in the backward fashion from the last job
and keep checking the job which can be taken if the last job has
already been taken. This job has an ending time which is less than or equal to the starting time of the last job. Add this job in your final answer list.

Now do the same procedure for this job. Scan through the list from this index and get a job such that its ending time is less than or equal to the starting time of the job last added to your final answer list. Repeat this until you are done.

Now just count the number of jobs in your final answer list.
This is the maximum number of jobs that can be done.

The whole procedure takes O(n lg n) + O(n) time.
(This can be reduced if you use non-comparison based sorting algorithm (like Radix Sort) to sort the starting times. Then the complexity becomes O(n)).